# Trying to find file extension on hidden download url

Tags: php, url, hidden

I am trying to make a script to take a downloadable file and put it onto my ftp server to then update a database. I cannot figure out what the url extention should be to able to make this work.

```
<?php
$src = fopen('https://www.atf.gov/firearms/docs/0516-ffl-listxlsx/download', 'r');
$dest1 = fopen('first1k.xlsx', 'w');
$dest2 = fopen('remainder.xlsx', 'w');

echo stream_copy_to_stream($src, $dest1, 19759460) . " bytes copied to first1k.txt\n";
echo stream_copy_to_stream($src, $dest2) . " bytes copied to remainder.txt\n";

?>
```

This is where I am trying to get the data from https://www.atf.gov/firearms/listing-federal-firearms-licensees-ffls-2016

Comment: Why not just `file_get_contents` or cURL?

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
$file = "0516.xlsx";
$url = 'https://www.atf.gov/firearms/docs/0516-ffl-listxlsx/download' ;

$handle = fopen("0516.xlsx", "w+");
fwrite($handle, file_get_contents($url));
rewind($handle);

$read = htmlentities(fread($handle, filesize($file)));

?>
```

fixed it out